# The callback sequence of viewDidAppear and viewDidDisappear between two view controllers

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller

As I know, there are at least two ways to present a UIViewController on another UIViewController, first is using presentModalViewController:animated: on UIViewController, another is using pushViewController:animated: on UINavigationController, it seems when 2 view controller changing their appearance, the invoke sequence of appear/disappear callbacks are different. Following is an example, A is a UINavigationController, and B is a normal view controller, the actual callback sequence are:
(1) A using presentModalViewController:animated: to show B:

```
[B viewWillAppear];  
[A viewWillDisappear];  
[B viewDidAppear];  
[A viewDidDisappear];
```

(2) A using pushViewController:animated: to show B:

```
[A viewWillDisappear];  
[B viewWillAppear];  
[A viewDidDisappear];  
[B viewDidAppear];
```

So my question is that, are these different callback sequence stable, or there are no definite sequence we can rely on? If they are stable, is there any document mentions this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIKit **should** work on the main thread, so I guess that the sequence is stable, **for the current SDK version**. However, as long as the behavior is not documented (and it is not to my knowledge), I would consider it subject to change without a notice.

I'm just curious; why do you need a deterministic sequence of those methods? Perhaps you can find a workaround (which might a better way of doing it).

Comment: There is a flag indicating the status change and this flag will be updated in viewDidDisappear method. If this callback sequence relies on Apple's internal implementation but not documented, and might be changed in the unknown future, I think my design should be improved. Thanks!

Comment: I need a deterministic sequence because two of my four tab-controlled view controllers use the shared accelerometer. Both need to set the shared delegate property to get accel data and remove the delegate (nil) when disappearing. I was using viewWillAppear (set) and viewWillDisappear (nil) for that, but sometimes the disappearing VC would nil the delegate after the appearing VC had set the delegate to itself. My solution: nil the delegate in viewWillDisappear and set the delegate in viewDidAppear. The disappearing VC's viewWillDisappear always happens before the appearing VC's viewDidAppear.

Comment: @Jeff Perhaps you have a good reason to do in such a way, but I would consider a different implementation. Like futureelite7 mentioned below, you will want to have your own control when you have a synchronization issue, rather than relying on Apple's calling sequence, even if it seems obvious that the calling sequence will not change after all (like in your case). For example, who knows UIKit will eventually be multithreaded on a multicore CPU arbitrated by graphic hardware, so there could be a race condition between viewWillDisappear of a leaving view and viewDidAppear of an incoming view?

Comment: @Jeff Although this specific example seems unlikely, it tells us that the best general approach is to enforce a deterministic order of events by synchronization codes.

Answer (score 0):

You will definitely want to implement some form of synchronization to enforce what you want to do. Relying on Apple's calling sequence of these functions is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I should not rely on Apple's internal behavior. Thanks!