# NSData writeToFile not completely written when reading

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am writing an iPhone app that allows you to browse images in one view, and create them in another.

The view that creates an image will write the image to the documents folder using the following code (when tapping a button to dismiss the view):

```
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

The browser view will load the image using:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Now this works perfectly 9 out of 10 times. 1 out of 10 the image is not completely written before I load it so the lower half of it will be black. Everything will be written eventually - if I reload the image in the browser, the full image is shown. I thought that these things would always be consistent within a single thread.

Can I do something to prevent this behavior?

Right now I'm thinking about passing the newly created image back to the browser but that just seems like a hack since the browser shows all your previously created images as well.

Comment: can you show **which** method is calling `writeToFile:atomically:`?  is it the button click handler, or `viewWillDisappear:`, or something else?  have you checked the return value of `writeToFile:`?  can you try the other variant of `writeToFile:` that allows you to pass in an `NSError`?

Comment: The image is saved when a button is clicked that then dismisses the view. The images is loaded in viewDidLoad in the browser view. Actually, it is hard to reproduce, I think it happens more like 1/100 or 1/1000. I saw it 3-4 times yesterday. Enough to be disturbing I'm afraid. It doesn't seem to happen now when I am flipping back and forth.

Comment: Also, I have seen this on multiple devices (4S, 3GS, iPad).

Comment: Here is a similar unanswered question: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/179315-can-append-spotlight-comments-after-writetofile-atomically.html. Perhaps there is a undocumented dependency on the run loop?

Comment: @Nate If you formulate your comment about "not maintaining its contract to complete the process" as an answer I will accept it. I don't think I will get a better answer than that. Simply delaying the load to the next run-loop cycle seems to do the trick so writeToFile may queue something to the run-loop. But it is meaningless to speculate really.

Comment: Ah, I'm not alone. I've found the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161079/nsdata-writetofileatomically-doesnt-immediately-save-the-file/11163298#comment14727763_11163298 (still no solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that the image is being saved on the main (UI) thread with `writeToFile:atomically:`, and the image is then being loaded also on the main thread, then it looks like there's a problem with that method maintaining its contract to complete the operation by the time the call returns.  iOS does sometimes have bugs, and maybe you found one.

I will also note, however, that one possible way that I've seen similar problems arise is when [assumptions are made about the order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5075222/the-callback-sequence-of-viewdidappear-and-viewdiddisappear-between-two-view-con) in which `viewWillAppear`, `viewDidDisappear`, etc. are called when leaving one view to display another.  So, I'd also make sure the image isn't saved in one of these methods.

Since you said the problem shows an image that is *half* visible, I would guess that this is not the case, but I include the warning for anyone else with a similar problem with order-of-operations.

Answer (score 1):

The standard solution for a process not finishing in time for the UI is to break it out into a new thread. Maybe you should create a separate thread to save the image and then notify the UI via a delegate method to update itself.

Comment: This won't help because now it is executed on the main thread so the operation is guaranteed to finish before the new view is displayed.

Comment: @rasmus, if there is any significant amount of work involved (and there must be if you're not seeing files reliably written in time), then you should be doing that work (saving) on a background thread.  You should not do everything on the UI thread as an attempt to force sequential execution.  Users don't like frozen UIs.

Comment: @Nate Well perhaps not but the delay is not my problem so this is not the solution to my problem either. Please read the question again. Also, the delay is not significant in this case. The problem is not performance/delay but correctness. A new thread will not fix that.

Comment: @rasmus The new thread *will* fix your problem. You want the image to show immediately. If it is not 100% written you will only see a part. The UI gets notified (presumably very quickly) and updates itself - now you see the complete image. If you want to avoid that effect you have to let your UI **wait** for the delegate notification before showing any part of the picture. In this case you might want to also show an activity indicator or the like.

Comment: @Mundi You are missing the point. Waiting a bit longer is just another hack. When writeToFile completes the file should be completely written. The new thread would also think that.

Comment: @rasmus, it sounds to me like `writeToFile:atomically:` then is not maintaining its contract to complete the process by the time the call returns.  If that's so, then you and I certainly don't know why that is.  It would be hasty, then, to assume that this couldn't be solved by another thread (or GCD queue).  I personally would never think to call `writeToFile:atomically:` from the UI thread with anything large.  If Apple's engineers think the same way, perhaps there's a bug you stimulated that could be worked around another way.  Does it hurt to try?

Comment: @Nate What I do now is a delayed load in the browser using `[self performSelector:@selector(loadPages:) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];`. This works as expected but I feel that this solution is a hack. I don't need another thread as these are quite small thumbnails so the delay is not noticeable (I have tested it on all target devices). I want to understand _why_ this is happening.